# update docker-compose, do I need to re-build image

Tags: docker, docker-compose

I have my containers running with `docker-compose.yml` configuration. After that, if I updated my `docker-compose.yml` file, do I need to rebuild the image or is it fine just restart the containers to have the updated configuration being applied?

Answer (score 9):

if the changes is only in docker-compose but not Dockerfile, then you do not need to re-build the image , however you need to make sure that compose is aware of the changes.

From the Docs using docker-compiose restart:

> If you make changes to your docker-compose.yml configuration these
>   changes are not reflected after running this command.

[Source](https://docs.docker.com/compose/reference/restart/)

the best way is to use `--force-recreate` , see more [this](https://docs.docker.com/compose/reference/up/)

if the change is in Dockerfile , then yes you need to rebuild the image.

Answer (score 3):

Try like this (In your working directory)

```
docker-compose down
```

> warning: It removes containers, volumes and networks.

then

```
docker-compose up
```

You don't need to recreate the new container image when you are changing in YAML file. Docker is capable enough to identify the changes in YAML file which will create an updated image when you run above command. This is the common step I used to follow in my work. Above command will recreate the containers when it finds the changes in the YAML file.

Comment: warning to mongodb users, if you used docker-compose up to create a mongodb database, this will delete the data. at least it deleted mine, would be nice if someone corrected me

Comment: @NathanTew , docker-compose down , Stops containers and removes containers, networks, volumes, and images , so yes Volumes will be deleted it is a dangerous Command to use ......, see https://docs.docker.com/compose/reference/down/

Answer (score 0):

If the definitions of the container images you're using haven't changed and you have only changed things like scaling parameters and environment variables you do not need to rebuild any container images.